# for loop not displaying the correct content

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I had a problem displaying the correct content while using the for loop. A big shout out @Alireza Ahmadi for resolving my problem.

I would still like to understand where my logic was flawed. If anyone could point out where I made the mistake, I would greatly appreciate it.

---

I would like to display different content in a tooltip using Tooltipster plugin. Tooltipster uses classes to display/change a tooltip.

The problem I was having (which AA resolved) was that each tooltip had the same content even though I used the for loop to go through all of the elements of the class (`animal`).

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mLthes38/1/)

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="textArea">
   Vastly different animals such as <span class="animal">whale</span> 
   and <span class="animal">dog</span> do have some things in common.
</div>
<div id="runTT">Run Tooltipster</div>
```

Tooltipster will look for a class (in this case `animal`) and change it's content.

I have a json/array:

```
        var animal = {
           "category": {
              "furry"  : "Are they furry: ",
              "legs"   : "Does it have legs: ",
              "mammal" : "Is it a mammal: "
           },"animals":{
                      "dog" : {
                         "furry" : "Yes.",
                         "legs"  : "Yes, 4.",
                         "mammal": "Yes."
                      },
                      "whale" : {
                         "furry" : "No.",
                         "legs"  : "None.",
                         "mammal": "Yes."
                      }
                }
        }
```

And this is the javascript + tooltipster code:

```
        var animalsClass;
        function getMarkedAnimals(){
            animalsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("animal");
        }

        function TooltipsterStuff(){
        $('.animal').tooltipster({
          contentAsHTML: true,
          functionReady: function(instance, helper) {
             for(let i = 0; i < animalsClass.length; i++){

                let pre0 = animal.category.furry;
                let pre1 = animal.category.legs;
                let pre2 = animal.category.mammal;
                let fix;
                let enter = "</br>";

                if(animal.animals.hasOwnProperty(animalsClass[i].textContent)){
                   
                    fix = animal.animals[animalsClass[i].textContent];

                    instance.content(
                    pre0 + fix.furry + enter +
                    pre1 + fix.legs + enter +
                    pre2 + fix.mammal
                   )
                }
             }
          }
        })
        }

        function doStuff(){
            getMarkedAnimals();
            TooltipsterStuff();
        }
    
        document.getElementById("runTT").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
```

So, by my (flawed) logic the loop was run. On `let i = 0` `animalsClass[0]` had the content of "dog", so the tooltip should change to "Yes.", "Yes, 4." and Yes.

On `i = 1` `animalsClass[1]` had the content of "whale", so the tooltips should change to: "No.", "No." and "Yes.".

It clearly doesn't work, so please point out where I made the error.

Thank you.

---

Edit:

So the problem is that `fix` is being overwritten due too the condition `hasOwnProperty` being true multiple times. Additionally, `content` is only being run once, so only the latest value is always used.

If `content` would be used/run multiple times then the `for` loop would work, but since `content` only runs once it only uses the latest value on all tooltips.

---

Edit 2:

So, the problem was that I was using one class (`animal`) to display multiple tooltips with different content. The for loop didn't work because the value isn't saved anywhere, it looks it up every time we hover over a class `animal`. To display different tooltips while using the same class we need to point out which `tag` we are hovering over and this is done with `helper.origin`.

Comment: Your logic is indeed wrong. You need to do something like get `helper.origin.textContent` to figure out which animal name is being hovered, and then access `animal.animals[helper.origin.textContent]` to get its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are in loop. Yes `animalsClass[0]` had the content of `dog` But you are in loop and then you go for `animalsClass[1]`!

Note that you need to check that tag you put on mouse, that is `helper.origin`.

`animalsClass` has `dog` and `whale` value and you check both of them in loop and both of them meet your condition `if(animal.animals.hasOwnProperty(animalsClass[i].textContent))`.

Comment: So basically it is overwriting the value of dog because the condition is true again. Would it work if I would use a "global" variable `var index;`, pass the value/number of `i` to `index`, `break` from the loop and repeat the loop starting with `index`?

Comment: First sentence is right. But how do you determine which index is hoverd?

Comment: I though it would change the default value of the `content` once the loop is run. Also edited the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch you

Comment: I thought that `functionReady` would change the default value/`content` of the tooltip. So the for loop would run `[i = 0]` would change the default value of dog to "Yes.", etc, and `[i = 1]` would change the default value of whale to "No.", etc. I thought this would work independently. Hover would display the new default value ie. "Yes.", etc.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I am using only once class, in this case `animal`. The default value of the tooltip for `animal` is "This is an animal". The tooltip needs to know which "animal" is being hovered over, to change the tooltip value. What I was initially thinking was that `content` would somehow save the values for dog, whale etc, but that doesn't work, in part because they are using the same class?

Comment: `The tooltip needs to know which "animal" is being hovered over, to change the tooltip value`. Absolutely you are right